# Kafka as event source when using Axon

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I'm studying Axon framework to try to use it in one of my microservices. I use Spring boot as my microservice and I want to use Axon framewrok for DDD and event sourcing. The thing is we already use Kafka in production and I'm not sure I can add another service (Axon serve) since it might consume resources I don't have (does it consume a lot of resources by the way?)
So I was thinking to use Kafka as event source and event routing with Axon.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kafka as **event bus** using the [Kafka extension for Axon](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka). You can't use Kafka as **event store** however. So you still need Axon Server or a relational database for the event store to use Axon Framework.

You could also combine those, e.g. have some events via Kafka, and some via Axon Server.